# How to Change the name of a Text File in a loop using visual c# and streamwriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am trying to write a loop that reads through a list, and saves parts of that list to different text files based on the hour the data was taken.  I want to name the text file based on the hour that the data was taken.

Here is the relevant code:

```
private StreamWriter filename;
string[] hour = {"00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23}

private void btn_hourfiles_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sizeoflist = Data_List.Count(); //This is the list containing the data
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeoflist,i++)
    {
       string[] listsplit = Data_List[i].Split(":");
       for (int j = 0; j<24; j++)
       {
           if (listsplit[2] == hour[j])
           {
            string[] datesplit = txt_DATE.Text.Split('-');//splits input date
            filename = datesplit[0] + '_' + dateplit[1] + '_' + datesplit[2] + '_' + hour[j] + '.dat'
            filename = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(Data_List[i], FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
            }
       }
    }
 }
```

The problem: I can't change the StreamWriter `filename`.  I get an error that says: `Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.IO.StreamWriter`

Question: How can I change the variable filename?

Comment: Well no - you're trying to assign a `string` value to `filename`. What did you *expect* that to do? It's not clear why you've got a private variable for the `StreamWriter` anyway... and I'd suggest that calling it `filename` isn't a great choice either. Where are you actually *writing* the data? Doing that with `File.WriteAllText` or whatever would probably make your life easier.

Comment: @Jonskeet I am trying to create a file with the name based on the hour, and write the data from that specific hour onto a file.  (But different hours should be in different files) for example there should be a file "2015_06_25_1200.dat" and "2015_06_25_1500.dat". Will File.WriteAllText do this?

Comment: Well `File.WriteAllText` writes the text you ask it to, into the file you ask it to. It's as simple as that. Again, you don't appear to be writing any data in the code you've provided - it doesn't help that we don't know what `txt_DATE` will have in it, or what `listsplit` will contain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you post is not getting compiled. Try next time to post the input so it will be simpler to help and answer to your question.
Anyway, I tried to help you according to what you wrote above, hope it will help you

class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyTest test = new MyTest();

        test.Foo();
    }
}

class MyTest
{
    private StreamWriter streamWriter;
    string[] hour = { "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23" };

    public void Foo()
    {
        string txt_DATE = "25-02-2015";
        string[] Data_List = { "12:05:10", "02:15:00", "14:15:22" };

        int sizeoflist = 3; // Data_List.Count(); //This is the list containing the data
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeoflist; i++)
        {
            string[] listsplit = Data_List[i].Split(':');
            for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++)
            {
                if (listsplit[2] == hour[j])
                {
                    string[] datesplit = txt_DATE.Split('-');//splits input date
                    var filename = datesplit[0] + '_' + datesplit[1] + '_' + datesplit[2] + '_' + hour[j] + ".dat";
                    streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:\\" + filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `StreamWriter` is declared thusly:

```
private StreamWriter filename;
```

but then assigned a string:

```
filename = datesplit[0] + '_' + dateplit[1] + '_' + datesplit[2] + '_' + hour[j] + '.dat'
```

Suggestion: use separate variables for filename and for the `StreamWriter`.